# Не обновляются данные по аяксу

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Есть форма `show` тикета на которую рендеряться два паршила: показать комментарии и создать новый комментарий. Оба должны обновляться по аяксу, но не обновляется, по `html` работает без проблем.

## app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb

```
 def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

## app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
def create
    @comment = @ticket.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket }
        format.js
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Something went wrong'
      render root_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @ticket.comments.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.user_id == current_user.id
      @comment.delete
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

## app/views/tickets/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @ticket.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

## app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.user.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.content %>
</p>

<% if comment.user == current_user %>
<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.ticket, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

## app/views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @ticket, @ticket.comments.build ], remote: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= current_user.email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :comment %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...', size: "50x5" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

## app/views/comments/create.js.erb

```
$('#comments_<%= @ticket.id %>').append("<%=j render 'comments/comment', ticket: @ticket, comment: @comment %>");
$('#comment_content_<%= @ticket.id %>').val('')
```

## app/views/comments/destroy.js.erb

```
$('#comments_<%= @ticket.id %>').html("<%= j render @ticket.comments, ticket: @ticket, comment: @comment %>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было навесить `id`

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<div class="comments" id="comments_<%= @ticket.id %>">
  <% if @ticket.comments %>
    <%= render @ticket.comments, ticket: @ticket %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= form.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...', size: "50x5", class: "comment_content", id: "comment_content_#{@ticket.id}" %>
```